# Multi INSERT with condition and SELECT return in one single request

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a messaging system, I want to record a new message.
For technical reasons There are two tables in my system. One referencing the conversations, and another referencing the messages linked to these conversations.

```
conversation

conversation_id
---------------
             3
             4
             8
            12
```

(*) conversation_id is a serial.

```
message

 message_id | conversation_id |      timestamp      | sender_id | receiver_id |            message           
------------+-----------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------
         12 |               3 | 2015-05-13 15:46:36 |         1 |           2 | Hello Bob! How are you doing?
         13 |               3 | 2015-05-13 15:55:10 |         2 |           1 | I'm fine, and you?
```

When the system records the new message I want it to automatically create the corresponding conversation if not already done.
I would like the statement to return the full conversation (meaning all the messages linked to the one that has just been added) as a result.

So the system would insert the conversation if not already created, then insert the message and finally return the whole conversation.

So I just want to provide this tuple to postGreSQL **(timestamp, sender_id, receiver_id, message)** and let it handle the conversation part (creation or selection).

And I want to get back the full conversation like if I were doing a:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE conversation_id="xxxx"
```

Is it possible to do all these operations in one single SQL statement?

I found out that we can use CTE's associated with INSERT and SELECT operations but I don't know how to articulate my specific request.

Comment: Must it be via a CTE? Are you open to PL/pgsql, a rule, or a trigger?

Comment: I'm opened to any solution. :-) But the simpler, the better... of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/plpgsql.html) stored procedure which accepts your tuple as parameters, checks your tables and does whatever insertions are warranted. Alternatively, you might be able to pull off something more slick using [rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rules-update.html) or [triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html), or even CTEs, but I am not slick enough to readily describe how.

Comment: I went for a stored procedure. This is working. I will post the solution for my specific issue since I haven't found anything looking like it on the web.